# Gemfire start Locator doesn't return prompt in Windows

Tags: java, windows, gemfire

The `gfsh> start locator` command as explained in [here](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/configuring/cluster_config/persisting_configurations.html) doesn't return the prompt back. I am using windows 8.1, pivotal-gemfire-9.0.4.

The log file looks like this. Am I missing something?
Any advice will be much appreciated!

```
 [info 2017/07/05 17:16:50.027 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1] Starting membership services

 [info 2017/07/05 17:16:51.170 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1]
 JGroups channel created (took 1143ms)

 [info 2017/07/05 17:16:51.202 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1]
 GemFire P2P Listener started on  null

 [info 2017/07/05 17:16:51.202 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1] This
 member is hosting a locator will be preferred as a membership
 coordinator

 [info 2017/07/05 17:16:51.217 IST myFirstLocator <Geode Failure
 Detection Server thread 0> tid=0x20] Started failure detection server
 thread on /10.XX.XXX.XXX:26618.

 [info 2017/07/05 17:16:51.223 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1] Peer
 locator is connecting to local membership services with ID
 10.XX.XXX.XXX(myFirstLocator:8824:locator)<ec>:1024

 [info 2017/07/05 17:17:01.237 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1]
 Stopping membership services

 [info 2017/07/05 17:17:01.240 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1]
 GMSHealthMonitor server socket is closed in stopServices().

 [info 2017/07/05 17:17:01.240 IST myFirstLocator <Geode Failure
 Detection Server thread 0> tid=0x20] GMSHealthMonitor server thread
 exiting

 [info 2017/07/05 17:17:01.241 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1]
 GMSHealthMonitor serverSocketExecutor is terminated

 [info 2017/07/05 17:17:01.249 IST myFirstLocator <main> tid=0x1]
 Stopping Distribution Locator on my.laptop[10334]
```

Comment: Can you please run the gfsh command with --log-level=DEBUG and post here?

Comment: @Swapnil Post is too long with log file contents. SO not allowing. is there anything specific you are interested in?

Comment: I would be curious to look at what is causing `Stopping membership services` to be logged. Can you try deleting your locator and server directories from any previous runs?

Comment: @Swapnil I have tried it. after a few unsuccessful attempts it somehow recovered and started working. But not sure what was the issue though. I tried outside firewall and within firewall and it is working within firewall also. But sometimes it fails to start w/o any apparent changes.